# Shortest way to get the A1 Notation (String) of a Range within a Google Sheet Cell Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I got:

```
=CustomFunction(B5:B38, $A40)
```

as the cells formula value. However, the range parameters are handed as their values, not as range objects.

What is the shortest way to convert those ranges into their Address string, like "B5:B38", while keeping the range address within the formula as one piece `B5:B38` (So it stays dynamic on sheet modifications)?

Comment: one could use ADDRESS() with ROW() and COLUMN() but that is a long solution and I am not sure if it would stay dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

**B5:B38** would be:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B5),COLUMN(B1))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(B38),COLUMN(B1),4))
```

---

shorter but not dynamic:

```
INDIRECT("B5:B38")
```

---

in some cases the first fx could be moded like:

```
INDIRECT("B5:"&ADDRESS(ROW(B38),COLUMN(B1)))
```

Comment: thx, hwr INDIRECT() returns a cell reference! I need to get the A1 Notation string!

Comment: ADRESS returns what I need but its bulky and is it dynamic?

Comment: @haemse yes, ADDRESS is fully dynamic